# SQL Pivot Half of table

Tags: sql, pivot, ssms

I have a table that consists of time information. It's basically:

Employee, Date, Seq, Time In, Time Out.

They can clock out multiple times a day, so I'm trying to get all of the clock outs in a day on one row. My result would be something like:

Employee, Date, TimeIn1, TimeOut1, TimeIn2, TimeOut2, TimeIn3, TimeOut3....

Where the 1, 2, and 3 are the sequence numbers. I know I could just do a bunch of left joins to the table itself based on employee=employee, date=date, and seq=seq+1, but is there a way to do it in a pivot? I don't want to pivot the employee and date fields, just the time in and time out.

Comment: When a user clocks in, I'm assuming the timeOut field is ```null```? Does ```seq``` reset per person/day, or is it a consistent sequence throughout? 5-10 sample rows would be pretty handy. Do you have a hard limit on the number of clock outs in a day? Would 10 clock ins/outs be sufficient, or do you need it to be more dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, it's possible.

The exact code will be updated if/when you provide sample data to clarify some points, but you can absolutely `pivot` the times out while leaving the employee/work date alone.

<sub>Sorry for the wall of code; none of the fiddle sites are working from my current computer</sub>

```sql
declare @test table (
    pk int,
    workdate date,
    seq int,
    tIN time,
    tOUT time
)

insert into @test values 
(1, '2020-11-25', 1, '08:00', null),
(1, '2020-11-25', 2, null, '11:00'),
(1, '2020-11-25', 3, '11:32', null),
(1, '2020-11-25', 4, null, '17:00'),
(2, '2020-11-25', 5, '08:00', null),
(2, '2020-11-25', 6, null, '09:00'),
(2, '2020-11-25', 7, '09:15', null),
-- new date
(1, '2020-11-27', 8, '08:00', null),
(1, '2020-11-27', 9, null, '08:22'),
(1, '2020-11-27', 10, '09:14', null),
(1, '2020-11-27', 11, null, '12:08'),
(1, '2020-11-27', 12, '01:08', null),
(1, '2020-11-27', 13, null, '14:40'),
(1, '2020-11-27', 14, '14:55', null),
(1, '2020-11-27', 15, null, '17:00')
 
select * 
from (

  /* this just sets the column header names and condenses their values */
  select 
    pk,
    workdate,
    colName = case when tin is not null then 'TimeIn' + cast(empDaySEQ as varchar) else 'TimeOut' + cast(empDaySEQ as varchar) end,
    colValue = coalesce(tin, tout)
  from (

      /* main query */
      select 
        pk,
        workdate, 
        /* grab what pair # this clock in or out is; reset by employee & date */
        empDaySEQ = (row_number() over (partition by pk, workdate order by seq) / 2) + (row_number() over (partition by pk, workdate order by seq) % 2),
        tin,
        tout
      from @test
  ) i
) a 
PIVOT (
 max(colValue) 
 for colName
 IN ( /* replace w/ dynamic if you don't know upper boundary of max in/out pairs */
   [TimeIn1],
   [TimeOut1],
   [TimeIn2],
   [TimeOut2],
   [TimeIn3],
   [TimeOut3],
   [TimeIn4],
   [TimeOut4]
 )
) mypivotTable
```

generates [these results](https://pasteboard.co/JC1V1GV.png).

(I would provide a fiddle demo but they're not working for me today)

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! 

The only thing I had to modify is that the time in and time out are recorded on the same line, so I just unioned a subquery of the time ins to a subquery of the time outs, and then used your code. Thanks a lot!